# Difference between void main and int main in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, standards, program-entry-point

Does it matter which way I declare the `main` function in a C++ (or C) program?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The difference is one is the correct way to define `main`, and the other is not.

And yes, it does matter. Either

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

or

```
int main()
```

are the proper definition of your `main` per the C++ spec.

`void main(int argc, char** argv)`

is not and was, IIRC, a perversity that came with older Microsoft's C++ compilers.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#main-returns-int

Comment: int main(void) is also proper

Comment: Actually, while that is okay, I think int main() is preferred to int main(void)

Comment: @Alan Why is that so?

Answer (score 29):

[Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) made this quite clear:

> The definition `void main()` is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C.

See [reference](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Answer (score 14):

You should use `int main`. Both the C and C++ standards specify that `main` should return a value.

Answer (score 9):

For C++, only int is allowed.  For C, C99 says only int is allowed.  The prior standard allowed for a `void` return.

In short, always `int`.

Comment: Returning an int is also required for C89.

Comment: The prior standard did not allow for a return of void. But one could leave off the return type and it would default to int. That still might work for some compilers. But that's not the same thing as void.

Answer (score 8):

The point is, C programs (and C++ the same) always (should?) return a success value or error code, so they should be declared that way.

Comment: Yes? And who will use that return code in your mars rover bare metal device? :)

Comment: That is a useful question — as a zen koan.

Answer (score 6):

A long time ago I found [this page (void main(void))](http://users.aber.ac.uk/auj/voidmain.shtml) which contained many reasons outside of the "the standard says it is not valid" argument. On particular operating systems/architectures it could cause the stack to become corrupted and or other nasty things to happen.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going by the spec, then you should always declare `main` returning an `int`.

In reality, though, most compilers will let you get away with either one, so the real difference is if you want / need to return a value to the shell.

Comment: You should always try to do things "by the spec" unless there is a compelling reason not to.  Granted, a lot of implementations allow void main, and other extensions.  This does not mean you should rely on implementation specific extensions.  In embedded applications, with no shell, void main is ok.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and agree with all of that.  For a while, I got into the habit of using void vs int as a kind of pesudo-comment about whether I was expecting to return a value, but now I just always use int.

Comment: Why is there value in doing the wrong thing (which happens to work in some cases), when the right thing is more work?

Comment: @Tom: because... the right thing was more work?  I'm not sure that sentence parses correctly.

Comment: @Ahoy - I missed one crucial word there... meant to say "...when the right thing is *no* more work"

Comment: @Tom - gotcha.  And frankly, I agree with you.

Comment: +1 for being concise. I dunno how I got here, I didn't need to know, but found myself reading the other answers. It really just takes a sentence or two.

Comment: @Trent The spec is a moving target. When I first used C++ (it was around 1992), void main(void) was the norm. And it makes sense it exists, given there is also bare metal embedded software where the end of main is end of "intelligent" device ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C++, `main()` must return `int`. However, C99 allows `main()` to have a non-`int` return type. Here is the excerpt from the C99 standard.

*5.1.2.2.1 Program startup*

*The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters:*

`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`

*or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):*

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

*or equivalent; **or in some other implementation-defined manner***.

Also note that gcc does compile `void main()` although practically, it does a `return 0;` on encountering a closing brace.

Comment: `gcc -pedantic`, however, will reject it. And not using `-pedantic` is just messed up.

Comment: If you rely on implementation-defined behavior, then your program is not standards-conforming.  Your compiler may accept it, but it's not valid C99, just foo-C99.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Hey, if we are not using ```gcc -pedantic```, does that mean we are not using the standard C? Secondly, I would appreciate it if you tell me where it is written.

Comment: @Jed Hey, if we are not using ```gcc -pedantic```, does that mean we are not using the standard C? Secondly, I would appreciate it if you tell me where it is written.

Comment: @NirajRaut No, on the contrary. I *always* use at least `-pedantic`, or `-pedantic-errors`. There’s absolutely no reason to use an incorrect return type, it’s just sloppy (but note that free-standing C implementations have different entry point functions!).

Comment: The other implementation defined part refers to the parameters, not the return type. `int` is still necessary.