# convert Hexadecimal number in Octal in c

Tags: c

I want a c program which ask for Hexadecimal number and gives output equivalent octal number. I use the code to convert int into octal using printf() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
Void main(){
  int i;
  printf("Enter the Hax number: ");
  scanf("%x",&i);
  printf("Octal equivalent of number is %o",i);
}
```

Comment: `Void` could be `void`, then it would be valid C, but should be `int`

Comment: What is your question? What problems do you have?

Comment: @Max: Could it be you are a spammer or why does your profile link to an adsite?

Comment: i want to convert Hax mumber into octal like
fD = 375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hexadecimal and Octal are just different representations of the same underlying number format. ie binary**. So no conversion is really happening in your example. Its just that you are interpreting/printing the same number in 2 different ways. And `printf` is indeed doing a good job in your example

```
Enter the Hax number: FF
Octal equivalent of number is 377
```

The only other problematic thing I can see is `Void` main :)

Comment: yes u r right but printf() does not convert the actual value i holds.
I want to convert this value

Answer (score 1):

other than your syntax errors this seems to be working, I just copied it. change

```
Void main()
```

to

```
int main()
```

or

```
//Since you are not using command line arguments this isn't necessary but valid
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

and add a

```
return 0; //not necessary but good practice
```

at the end of the method

EDIT:

also

```
void main()
```

will compile with many C compilers, but is invalid C (no current and prior standard sanctions it). Use `int` instead.

Comment: @Alok I just coded it and it compiles and runs fine. (There is a warning under gcc with the `-Wall` option specified but not otherwise)

Comment: @twain249 - compiling is not enough to say if the code is valid C.  The C standard defines what is valid C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main

Comment: @Alok and twain: I looked it up, I must apologize, void main() is indeed not sanctioned. +1 for mentioning that compiling is not enough.

Comment: @Alok changed it from is valid to will compile and said not to use it.

Comment: I remove my initial comment as I see it is voted up for untruth, sorry again.

Comment: @twain249: I refined your phrase further.