# Return type of main function

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)
>   [Difference between void main and int main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main)

I have always been using the main method in C like

```
void main(){ // my code }
```

and it works pretty well for me.
I also know about the other  `int` return type:

```
int main(void)
int main()
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

But I have  not been able to find any resource that says that I can use `void` as a return type. Every book suggests that the return type must be `int` or else it be omitted. Then why does `void main()` work?

Is this dependent on the version of C that I am using? Or does it work because I use a C++ IDE?  Please reply specific to C and not C++.

Comment: [What should main() return in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only book authors seem to be privy to the place where a return type of `void` for `main()` is allowed.  The C++ standard forbids it completely.

The C standard says that the standard forms are:

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }
```

allowing alternative but equivalent forms of declaration for the argument types (and the names are completely discretionary, of course, since they're local variables to the function).

The C standard does make small provision for 'in some other implementation defined manner'.  The ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard says:

> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
>   returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   main function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.
>
> <sup>11)</sup> In accordance with 6.2.4, the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration declared in main
>   will have ended in the former case, even where they would not have in the latter.

This clearly allows for non-`int` returns, but makes it clear that it is not specified.  So, `void` might be allowed as the return type of `main()` by some implementation, but you can only find that from the documentation.

(Although I'm quoting C2011 standard, essentially the same words were in C99, and I believe C89 though my text for that is at the office and I'm not.)

Incidentally, Appendix J of the standard mentions:

> ### J.5 Common extensions
>
> The following extensions are widely used in many systems, but are not portable to all
>   implementations. The inclusion of any extension that may cause a strictly conforming
>   program to become invalid renders an implementation nonconforming. Examples of such
>   extensions are new keywords, extra library functions declared in standard headers, or
>   predefined macros with names that do not begin with an underscore.
>
> #### J.5.1 Environment arguments
>
> In a hosted environment, the `main` function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`,
>   that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to `char`, each of which points to a string
>   that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program
>   (5.1.2.2.1).

### Why does `void main()` work?

The question observes that `void main()` works.  It 'works' because the compiler does its best to generate code for programs.  Compilers such as GCC will warn about non-standard forms for `main()`, but will process them.  The linker isn't too worried about the return type; it simply needs a symbol `main` (or possibly `_main`, depending on the system) and when it finds it, links it into the executable.  The start-up code assumes that `main` has been defined in the standard manner.  If `main()` returns to the startup code, it collects the returned value as if the function returned an `int`, but that value is likely to be garbage.  So, it sort of seems to work as long as you don't look for the exit status of your program.

Comment: Note: Microsoft does define `void main()` with various argument lists as valid.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/15168) for the full details.

Answer (score 2):

From the [horse's mouth](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
> prototype for this function. It shall be deﬁned with a return type of `int` and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
>     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
> used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>9)</sup>
> or in some other implementation-deﬁned manner.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>9) Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name deﬁned as int, or the type of argv can be written as
> char ** argv, and so on.</sup>

The loophole is the "some other implementation-defined manner".  An implementation *may* allow `main` to return `void` (or any other type), but it *must explicitly document* that such a signature is allowed.  Otherwise the behavior is undefined, meaning the compiler can do anything it wants.  The program may execute without any problems.  It may execute, but leave the environment in a bad state.  It may crash on exit.  It may fail to load at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on the compiler you are using, but void main is not compilable everywhere. I have seen compilers that won't compile a program with void main. I can not recall the particular case(for c), but I know for sure this happens in g++(yes I know this is  c++).

Answer (score 0):

The standard calls for `main()` to return `int`, but a lot of C compilers allow you to specify the return type of `main()` as `void`.

I recommend you get into the habit of returning `int`. Adding a

```
return 0;
```

to the end of your `main()` isn't too much effort.

Comment: There is no need for `return 0` — falling out of `main` without returning a value guarantees returning `0`.

Comment: @hamstergene I dont think its guaranteed. Any citation?

Comment: See 5.1.2.2.3 above in Jonathan Leffler's answer. It is also true for C++.

Comment: Either way, I think it is neater to explicitly add `return 0;` to the end. I usually have some `return 1;`s near the start of the main in case of errors, so having the `return 0` makes the program more _complete_.

Answer (score -1):

I was acceptable in C89 but it is no longer considered "safe". Under C99, it is no longer acceptable.

http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284376&answer=1044841143

Comment: Void main() has never been allowed by the standard. The article you refer to is about "no return type at all" -->> defaults to int.