# Simple C Program Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am just learning C and I am trying to write a simple program to do a simple calculation. The program compiles just fine, however when I enter values and attempt to run it, I get "Segmentation Fault". Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and what exactly a segmentation fault is?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float main()
{
  int price, service;
  float annual, value;

  printf("Enter the purchase price, years of service, annual depreciation:\n");
  scanf("%d %d %f\n", price, service, annual);

  value = (annual * service) - price;

  printf("The salvage value of the item is %f", value);
  return 0;
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need `scanf("%d %d %f\n", &price, &service, &annual);`

Comment: why is your `main()` returning a `float` rather than an `int`?

Comment: I have changed it to int main(), thank you for catching that.

Comment: You should enable all warnings and debugging information when compiling. E.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (then improve the code till no warnings are given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your program. First, `main()` should return an `int`, typically zero for success and some other value for failure. Change `float main ()` to `int main()` and see if that makes a difference.

Second, as the other two answers have pointed out, your arguments to `scanf()` should be the addresses of the variables that will hold the input values:

```
scanf("%d %d %f\n", &price, &service, &annual);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong

```
 scanf("%d %d %f\n", price, service, annual);
```

should be:

```
 scanf("%d %d %f\n", &price, &service, &annual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
scanf("%d %d %f\n", price, service, annual);
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d %f", &price, &service, &annual);
```

because `scanf` always expect a pointer as its argument. Also remove `\n` from format specifier of `scanf()`
Also change `float main()` to [int main()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915776/2455888).

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was the problem! I guess the segmentation fault is because of the pointers?

Comment: Yes. This is mainly because of the missing `&` here in `scanf` arguments. `scanf` always expects a pointer (address) as its argument