# What is the difference in 'for' and 'while' between or without brackets?

Tags: c

As the title says, I've written some codes and tested it but for some reason I still can't understand it.

```
for (…)
  {
    …
  }
```

versus

```
for (…)
  …
```

and

```
while (…)
  {
    …
  }
```

versus

```
while (…)
  …
```

Also, I've seen that in some cases `main` works without the `int`, why does this happen? And, how is the proper way to write `main`?

Sorry for double question, I have many doubts (specially arrays).
Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Feel free to ask multiple questions here, but don't group them together.

Comment: `main` must always return int.. `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.. You need to learn about scopes to know the difference between `for (...) { blah; }` and `for (...) blah;`

Comment: Sorry Shomz. Also, I'm still not into arguments or pointers (I do know they exist and what they are but not using them yet).

Comment: As of the old C89/C90 standard, the `int` could be omitted; the return type was still implicitly taken as `int`. C99 dropped the implicit `int` rule, but not all compilers enforce the newer standards. You can get away with writing `main()` with some compilers, but you should always write `int main(void)` instead (or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`).

Comment: No need to be sorry. I see you're new here, so I'm just giving you advice to keep your questions simple and accurate, no need to squeeze multiple questions into one.

Comment: I cannot mark it as a duplicate because you have asked  multiple question in one but look here for the question about `main`'s return type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you leave out the curly braces, the body of the loop is just a single statement. The braces allow you to put multiple statements in the body.

**With braces:**

```
while (...) {
    statement1;
    statement2;
    statement3;
}
```

All 3 statements will be executed repeatedly.

**Without braces:**

```
while (...) 
    statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
```

Only `statement1` will be executed repeatedly. The other two statements will be executed once after the loop finishes.

It's a good idea to always use braces. See

[Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of a `for` or `while` statement (also an if` statement) is such that it always controls exactly one sub-statement.

A `while` loop has the form:

```
while ( expression ) statement
```

Adding curly braces simply means that you're using a different kind of statement. A *block* or *compound statement* consists of a `{`, followed by zero or more declarations or statements, followed by a `}`.

Note that the braces are not part of the syntax of the `while` statement.

So if I write:

```
while (foo)
    puts("hello");
```

the `while` statement controls a single sub-statement, which happens to be a function call. If I write:

```
while (foo) {
    puts("hello");
    puts("good-bye");
}
```

the `while` statement *still* controls a single sub-statement, but this time it happens to be a compound statement, which itself contains two sub-statements.

The advantage of using a compound statement, as others have pointed out, is that it can help avoid errors when you want to add something to the body of a loop.  It's not uncommon to see incorrect code like this:

```
while (foo)
    puts("hello");
    puts("good-bye");
```

This is perfectly legal, and most compilers won't complain about it, but the second call is not controlled by the `while`; it will be executed just once, after the `while` loop has finished. By consistently using curly braces from the beginning, you can avoid this particular class of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

`for`/`while` without {} means that only the next statement will be part of the loop, any statements after that are outside the loop. This leads to many bugs and probably not a good general practice. It's always a good idea to add the {} because then if you ever add more code to your loop you won't cause yourself a headache if you forget to add {} later.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, if you leave out the block C control structures (while, if, for, else...) they will generally iterate on or execute the next statement.  This is a bad idea.  It turns out you can put a lot of things in place of the block in a `while` or `for` loop, most of them are also a bad idea.  Let's go to the C99 standard.

> ```
> 6.8.5 Iteration statements Syntax
>   iteration-statement:
>       while ( expression ) statement
>       do statement while ( expression ) ;
>       for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement 
>       for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> ```

Notice they all take "statements" not "blocks".  What's a "statement"?

> ```
> 6.8 Statements and blocks Syntax
>   statement:
>       labeled-statement
>       compound-statement
>       expression-statement
>       selection-statement
>       iteration-statement
>       jump-statement
> ```

Long story short, a "compound-statement" is a block, an "expression-statement" is a single expression, and we'll skip the rest right now.  This is a while loop with an expression-statement.

```
while( condition )
    do_something;
```

This is a while loop with a compound-statement.

```
while( condition ) {
    do_this;
    and_this;
    and_this;
}
```

It's a good idea to *always* use blocks, even for one line.  Why?  Because you can easily fool yourself into thinking you're looping over statements you're not.

```
while( condition )
    do_this;
    and_this;
    and_this;
```

Those last two statements sure look like they're part of the loop, but they're not.

A common mistake is to write something like this:

```
if( condition )
    do_this;
else
    do_something_else;
    and_also_this;
```

`and_also_this` will always be executed.

It is much safer to always include the block.

[The main question has already been answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915713/return-type-of-main-method-in-c/10915776#10915776).