# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|

Tags: c

There was a problem with this code in this link -
 [Why does it say 'expected declaration specifiers before 'main''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575750/why-does-it-say-expected-declaration-specifiers-before-main)

But the answers there were not satisfying. And there are a lot of problems that were not addressed at all.

Here is some of the compiler output

```
|20|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token  
|14|error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition  
|113|error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token   
|139|error: expected '(' before '{' token  
|169|error: expected ':' or '...' before ';' token   
|276|error: redefinition of 'getFinalHand'   
|14|note: previous definition of 'getFinalHand' was here|
```

I really don't know how to deal with these.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

void printGreeting();
int getBet();
char getSuit(int suit);
char getRank(int rank);
void getFirstHand(int cardRank[], int cardSuit[]);
void getFinalHand
(int cardRank[], int cardSuit[], int finalRank[], int finalSuit[], int 
ranksinHand[], int suitsinHand[])
int analyzeHand(int ranksinHand[], int suitsinHand[]);


main()
{
int bet;
int bank = 100;
int i;
int cardRank [5];
int cardSuit [5];
int finalRank[5];
int finalSuit[5];
int ranksinhand[13];
int suitsinhand[4];
int winnings;
time_t t;
char suit, rank, stillPlay;


printGreeting();


do{
bet = getBet();
srand(time(&t));
getFirstHand(cardRank, cardSuit);
printf("Your five cards: \n\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    suit = getSuit(cardsSuit[i]);
    rank = getRank(cardRank[i]);
    printf("Card #%d: %c%c\n\n", i+1, rank, suit);
}

for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
    suitsinHand[i] = 0;
}
for (i=0; i < 13; i++)
{
    ranksinHand[i] = 0;
}

getFinalHand(cardRank, cardSuit, finalRank, finalSuit, ranksinHand, 
suitsinHand);

printf("Your five final cards:\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    suit = getSuit(finalSuit[i]);
    rank = getRank(finalRank[i]);
    printf("Card #%d: %c%c\n\n", i+1, rank, suit);
}

winnings = analyzeHand(ranksinHand, suitsinHand);
printf("You won %d!\n\n", bet*winnings);
bank = bank - bet + (bet*winnings)
printf("\n\nYour bank is now %d.\n\n", bank);
printf("Want to play again? ");
scanf(" %c", &stillPlay);
}while (toupper(stillPlay) == 'Y');



 return;
 }

 /*************************************************************************/


 void printGreeting();
 {

 printf("**********************************************************\n\n");
 printf("\n\n\tWelcome to the Absolute Beginner's Casino\n\n");
 printf("\tHome of the Video Draw Poker");
 printf("**********************************************************\n\n");

 printf("Here are the rules\n");
 printf("You start with 100 credits, and you make a bet from");
 printf("1 to 5 credits.\n");
 printf("You are dealt 5 cards, and then you choose which ");
 printf("cards to keep");
 printf("or discard\n");
 printf("You want to make the best possible hand.\n");
 printf("\nHere is the table for winnings (assuming a ");
 printf("bet of 1 credit):");
 printf("\nPair \t\t\t\t1 credit");
printf("\nTwo pairs\t\t\t2 credits");
printf("\nThree of a kind\t\t\t3 credits");
printf("\nStraight \t\t\t4 credits");  
printf("Flush\t\t\t\t5 credits");
printf("Full House\t\t\t8 credits");
printf("Four of a Kind\t\t\t10 credits");
printf("Straight Flush\t\t\t20 credits");
printf("\n\nHave fun!!\n\n"); 
}


 void getFirstHand(int cardRank[], int cardSuit[]);
 {
int i,j;
int carDup;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
carDup = 0;
do{
    cardRank[i] = (rand() % 13);
    cardSuit[i] = (rand() % 4);

    for (j=0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if ((cardRank[i] == cardRank[j] &&
             cardSuit[i] == cardSuit[j]))
        {
            carDup = 1;
        }
    }
 }while (carDup == 1;);
 }
 }

 char getSuit(int suit)
 {
 switch
 {
case 0:
    return('C');
case 1:
    return('D');
case 2:
    return('H');
case 3:
    return('S');
}
}

char getRank(int rank)
{
switch (rank)
{
 case 0:
    return('A');
case 1:
    return('2');
case 2:
    return('3');
case 3:
    return('4');
case 4:
    return('5');
case 5:
    return('6');
case 6:
    return('7');
case 7;
    return('8');
case 8:
    return('9');
case 9:
    return('T');
case 10:
    return('J');
case 11:
    return('Q');
case 12:
    return('K');
}
}
int getBet()
{
int bet;
do
 {
printf("How much do you want to bet?(Enter a number");
printf("from 1 to 5, or 0 to quit the game): ");
scanf(" %d", &bet);

if (bet >= 1 && bet <= 5)
{
    return(bet);
}
else if (bet == 0)
{
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    printf("\n\nPlease enter a bet from 1-5 or ");
    printf("0 to quit the game\n\n");
}
}while ((bet < 0) || (bet > 5));
}

int analyzeHand(int ranksinHand[], int suitsinHand[])
{
 int num_consec = 0;
int i, rank, suit;
int straight = FALSE;
int flush = FALSE;
int four = FALSE;
int three = FALSE;
int pairs = 0;


for (suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
if (suitsinHand[suit] == 5)
    flush = TRUE;
rank = 0;
 while (ranksinHand[rank] == 0)
rank++;
for (; rank < 13 && ranksinHand[rank]; rank++)
num_consec++;
if(num_consec == 5) {
straight = TRUE;
}
for (rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++){
if (ranksinHand[rank] == 4)
    four == TRUE;
if (ranksinHand[rank] == 3)
    three == TRUE;
if (ranksinHand[rank] == 2)
    pairs++;
}
if (straight && flush){
printf("Straight Flush\n\n");
return(20);
}
 else if (four){
printf("Four of a kind\n\n");
return (10);
}
else if (three && pairs == 1){
printf("Full House\n\n");
return (8);
}
else if (flush){
 printf("Flush\n\n");
return (5);
}
else if (straight){
printf("Straight\n\n");
return (4);
}
else if (three){
printf("Three of a Kind\n\n");
return (3);
}
else if (pairs == 2){
printf("Two Pairs\n\n");
return (2);
}
else if (pairs == 1){
printf("Pair\n\n");
return (1);
}
else{
printf("High Card\n\n");
return (0);
}
 }

void getFinalHand
(int cardRank[], int cardSuit[], int finalRank[], int finalSuit[], int 
ranksinHand[], int suitsinHand[])
{
int i, j, carDup;
char suit, rank, ans;

for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
suit = getSuit(cardSuit[i]);
rank = getRank(cardRank[i]);
printf("Do you want to keep card #%d: %c%c", i+1, rank, suit);
printf("\nPlease answer (Y/N):");
scanf(" %c", &ans);
if (toupper(ans) == 'Y')
{
    finalRank[i] = cardRank[i];
    finalSuit[i] = cardSuit[i];
    ranksinHand[finalRank[i]]++;
    suitsinHand[finalSuit[i]]++;
    continue;
}
else if (toupper(ans) == 'N')
{
    carDup = 0;
    do{
        carDup = 0;
        finalRank[i] = (rand() % 13);
        finalSuit[i] = (rand() % 4);

        for (j=0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if((finalRank[i] == finalRank[j]) && (finalSuit[i] == 
  finalSuit[j]))
            {
                carDup = 1;
            }
        }

        for (j=0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if((finalRank[i] == finalRank[j]) && (finalSuit[i] == 
finalSuit[j]))
            {
                carDup = 1;
            }
        }
    }while (carDup == 1);
    ranksinHand[finalRank[i]]++;
    suitsinHand[finalSuit[i]]++;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Another useful technique is indentation.

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [**C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (draft n1570)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also: [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: getFinalHand declaration missing a semicolon. Thereafter the compiler will struggle to make sense of the code, so fixing that will likely resolve others.  Don't _count_ error messages, one error can precipitate multiple messages. - fix the first one, re-compile.  No doubt other similar typos.  Your poor code layout is probably not helping you here.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare your program to a HelloWorld or something from a tutorial. The usual head of `main()` (in the simplest case) should be `int main(void)`.

As a side note:
You need to add return statements to anything not returning void, e.g. lines 153, 188, 213, and to take care with WHAT you return in line 81.
You need to take care with case-sensitivity of identifiers, e.g. lines 29, 30.
You need to decide on what you want to switch in line 142.
You need to see the difference between `==` and `=` in lines 240,242.
You seem to be fighting a war against semicolons `;` in lines 14, 16, 73, 116, 138, 173, please make peace.

I am not saying that the program will work as expected after fixing those things, I did not care trying to figure that out. But if you copied from somewhere, it probably will. Copying code this way is however unlikely to teach you anything.

In short, you need to learn making small working programs and extending them slowly, in small, verified steps.
I cannot imagine how you managed to write code like that, over 300 lines, without intermediate steps. The only thing I can imagine is that you copied this code from somewhere, manually typing. That seems consistent with the kind of mistakes in there.
Learn what the compiler warnings mean (using at least `gcc -Wall`), by slowly working your way upwards through some tutorials. When manually copying tutorial code, you might make a few mistakes of this sort and have an easier life fixing them, one after the other.
I recommend to play with tutorial code (after getting it right, to do what it is supposed to), by changing little things. E.g. change the output from "Hello world." to "Hi Praveen.", change the number of loops in a `for (...;...;...)` and things like that. Get some practice that way, learn to predict which edits to code cause which changes to behaviour.

Another very helpful technique for understanding errors in your code (i.e. not only concerning making the asking of questions on StackOverflow more productive and easier), is the concept of
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  , which is worth studying.
It is extremely helpful for yourself, being a great debugging technique.
The example in this question is very far away from being "Minimal" for reproducing the problem with the head of `main()` - and that distracts you from fixing your problem.

Comment: @Nimantha Feel free to fix them. I hope you noticed that while I undid your edit as a whole, I took in the point you were making and incorporated it in a different way. I will do  typo hunt myself now.