# So if I scanf("%c",del), before reading the string, it works, but after it doesn't

Tags: c, string, scanf

So I made a program for deleting a char from a string, it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* deleteChar(char* texto,int n,char del,int i,int j)
{
    /*for(i=0,j=0;i<n;i++)
        if(texto[i]!=del)
        {
            texto[j]=texto=i;
            j=+1;
        }
        for(n-i;n-i<n;i--)
            texto[n-i]=NULL;
        return(texto);*/

    if(i!=n)
    {
        if(texto[i]!=del)
        {
            texto[j]=texto[i];
            j+=1;
        }
        i+=1;
        texto=deleteChar(texto,n,del,i,j);
    }
    else
    {
        i=i-j;
        for(n-i;n-i<n;i--)
            texto[n-i]=NULL;
        return(texto);
    }
}

void main()
{
    char del;
    printf("Remover: \n");
    scanf("%c",&del);

    char* texto;
    texto=(char*)calloc(0,sizeof(char));
    printf("Texto: \n");
    scanf("%s",texto);
    int n=0;
    n=strlen(texto);

    /*char del;
    scanf("%c",&del);*/

    texto=deleteChar(texto,n,del,0,0);
    printf("%s ",texto);
}
```

Focus on `main()`, for some reason if I `scanf("%c",&del)` after getting my string, the program breaks (before even getting the `del` input'), but if I do it after it works greatly.
I have no idea why.

Comment: `calloc(0,sizeof(char));` doesn't give you enough space to use with `scanf("%s", texto)`

Comment: If you put `scanf("%c",&del)` after the string input, it will take the newline remaining in the input buffer. Put a space before `%c` as in `scanf(" %c",&del)` because unlike most format specifiers, `%c` does not automatically skip whitespace remaining from the previous input. This one of the most frequent C problems.

Comment: Use good names instead of i,j.  Also, there is no reason to pass 0,0 as the initial values, they should be declared and initialized inside the routine.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allocating space for one `char`

```
texto = (char*)calloc(0, sizeof(char));
```

You need to allocate enough space for your entire string, including NULL terminator, this will let you have a string of 20 chars plus a NULL terminator

```
texto = (char*)calloc(21,  sizeof(char));
```

And you should at the very least control how many characters you can read into your string in `scanf()` so you can't overflow your buffer

```
scanf("%20s", texto);
```

For safer and more robust user input, you should look up `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have redeclared `del` in line:

```
char del;
scanf("%c",&del);
```

So just remove second deceleration of `del`.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem reading `del` after reading the string because, `scanf()` used to read the string leaves the final `\n` in the input buffer unconsumed if your format string is like

```
scanf("%s", stringname);
scanf("%c", charactername);
```

You could solve this by

```
scanf("%s", stringname);
scanf(" %c", charactername);
```

adding a space before the `%c` in the `scanf()` used to read the character. This will consume any white space character still left in the input buffer before reading the actual character.

This is because for `%c` leading white space is not automatically skipped.

Note that you are allocating memory only for a single character with

```
char* texto;
texto=(char*)calloc(0,sizeof(char));
```

instead you could do

```
char* texto;
texto=calloc(0,sizeof(char)*10);
```

where `10` is the size of the string including the `\0` character. So you can read maximum 9 characters into `texto` otherwise overflow will occur.

To avoid the overflow, while reading with `scanf()` use a width specifier as in

```
scanf("%9s", texto);
```

You don't need to explicitly cast the return value of `calloc()` in C. The conversion to `char *` from the `void *` returned by `calloc()` will be done implicitly.

And to delete you could just do

```
char* deleteChar(char* texto,int n,char del,int i,int j)
{
    char *ptr=strchr(texto, del);
    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        sprintf(texto, "%.*s%s", ptr-texto, ptr+1);
    }   
}
```

You don't need to return `texto` because what was passed is an array.

```
char* deleteChar(char* texto,int n,char del,int i,int j)
{
    char *ptr=strchr(texto, del);
    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        sprintf(texto, "%.*s%s", ptr-texto, texto, ptr+1);
    }   
}
```

`strchr()` is used to get the first occurrence of a character in a string.

Also, the return type of `main()` shouldn't be `void`. See [Return type of main function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10915713/5375464).