# Simple Vertical Histogram in C

Tags: c

The exercise was to print a histogram of the different characters in the input. At the bottom is my code where I break the different characters into 3 categories a,b, or other, to extrapolate to more categories of characters if the code is successful. But it doesn't have the output I want, for example, for input `ab cd` I expect

```
  x
xxx
---
abo
  t
  h
  e
  r
```

but all I get is

```
---
abo
  t
  h
  e
  r
```

Here's my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int i,c,b, max;
int array[3] = {0,0,0};


while( (c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(c== 'a')
    ++array[0];
    else if(c== 'b')
    ++array[1];
    else if(c=='\n' ||c=='\t' || c==' '){}
    else ++array[2];
    }

array[0]=max;
i=0;

 while(i<3){
    if(max>=array[i])
        {}
    else array[i]=max;

    ++i;
 }

i=0;
max=b;
while(i<b){
    if(array[0]>=max){
        putchar('x');}
    else putchar(' ');


    if(array[1]>=max) {
        putchar('x');}
    else putchar(' ');


    if (array[2]>=max){
        putchar('x\n');}
    else putchar(' \n');
    --max;
    ++i;


    }

printf("---\nabo\n  t\n  h\n  e\n  r");


}
```

Comment: The assignments `array[0]=max;` and `else array[i]=max;`should probably be turned the other way around (max=...). You want to assign the value to max and not the other way around. Similarly the line `max=b` should be changed to `b=max` since you want to set the variable _b_ to the current value of _max_ and not the other way around.

Comment: What happens if you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: You assigned `max = b` without initializing `b`!

Comment: I recommend that you break your code into smaller functions. This makes it easier to see what each part is doing.

Answer (score 5):

There's a good bit wrong with your code.

1. Never do - `main()`

   You should be using `int main(void){...}` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid).
2. You're hard coding numbers into your code. Provide constant variables instead. There are logical exceptions to this but numbers generally have meaning so state it. 
   `unsigned const int LETTERS = 3;`
3. You take the time to increment `array[0]` counting the occurrences of `'a'`, but then assign it the value of `max` directly afterwards without using that value or storing it somewhere else.
4. You assign `array[0]` after the first `while(){...}` but `max` has not been initialized, so it's "garbage".
5. Here -`if(max>=array[i]){}` you don't do anything in the body??
6. You assign `max` the value of `b` - *again* "garbage"!
7. You should `return ...;` from your `main` function. You'll have to see for yourself the options you have there. Note: If you follow "1." you'll have no choice but to follow this one.
8. Your formatting, if not in your "real" code, in the post is less than desirable (i.e.; it's not very easily read.

Fix those things and you'll probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

- `array[0] = max` to   `max = array[0]`  *(otherwise `max` will take some garbage value)*
- `max = b` to `b = max`                  *(otherwise `b` will take some garbage value)*
- `putchar('x\n')` to `{ putchar('x'); putchar('\n')}`.
  *(It is important to note here, that `putchar()` prints only one character at once but you used `putchar('x\n')` to print two characters `x` and `\n` together!)*

then your program will give desired output.
Here is your working code with changes mentioned above:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,c,b, max;
    int array[3] = {0,0,0};


    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF){
       if(c == 'a')
            ++array[0];
       else if(c == 'b')
            ++array[1];
       else if(c =='\n' || c =='\t' || c == ' ')
            ;
       else ++array[2];
    }

 max = array[0];
 i=0;

 while(i<3){
    if(max < array[i])
        max = array[i];
i++;        
}

i=0;
b = max;
while(i < b){
    if(array[0] >= max)
        putchar('x');
    else 
        putchar(' ');


    if(array[1] >= max)
        putchar('x');
    else 
        putchar(' ');


    if (array[2] >= max)
    {
        putchar('x');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    else 
        putchar('\n');
    --max;
     ++i;


  }

printf("---\nabo\n  t\n  h\n  e\n  r");

return 0;
}
```