# In my below code,why value and address of ptr[0] is same. Same behavior for ptr[1] and ptr[2]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In my below code,why value and address of `ptr[0]` is same. Same behavior for `ptr[1]` and `ptr[2]`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var=100;
    int(*ptr)[5];//array of pointer.

    ptr=&var;
    printf("Value of var is  : %d\n",var);
    printf("Address of var : %u\n",&var);
    printf("Value inside ptr after ptr=&var : %u\n",ptr[0]);
    printf("Value of ptr[0] is  : %d\n", ptr[0]);
    printf("Adress of ptr[0] is  : %u\n",&ptr[0]);

    printf("Value of ptr[1] is  : %d\n",ptr[1]);
    printf("Adress of ptr[1] is  : %u\n",&ptr[1]);

    printf("Value of ptr[2] is  : %d\n",ptr[2]);
    printf("Adress of ptr[2] is  : %u\n",&ptr[2]);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: use `%p` for printing address.

Comment: see right-left rule, http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Comment: As @SouravGhosh said: the correct way to print a pointer is: `printf("Address of ptr: %p\n", (void *) &some_var);`. It's one of few cases where you actually need the `void *` cast

Comment: suppose what  if int var=100; is replaced by int var[5]={10,20,30,40,50}; im getting same value and address for ptr[0], ptr[1] and ptr[2]

Answer (score 4):

In your case

```
  int(*ptr)[5];//array of pointer.
```

is not exactly *"array of pointer."*. Rather, it is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.

So,

```
 ptr=&var;
```

is wrong because, `&var` is not a pointer to an array.

Then, accessing `ptr[1]` is absolutely wrong because of out-of-bound access. `ptr` here, is not an array all by itself.

You may want to rewrite

```
  int(*ptr)[5];
```

as

```
   int *ptr[5];
```

That said,

1. `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, as per the standard.
2. Always use `%p` to print the address. Also, cast the pointer to `(void *)` before passing as argument, as `%p` expects a `void *`.

Comment: `int f(void)` is very unreadable than `int f()` and also involves lesser keystrokes. Bjanre called the former an "abomination". One might argue that his comment was for C++ and not C, but in this context it applies to both. Also the standard just gives a guideline there not a rigid rule: _It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
parameters […] or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner._

Comment: @legends2k Don't listen to Bjarne, he is an abomination. In **C**, unlike C++, there is a distinct difference between `(void)` and `()`, namely that the latter, when lacking a proper function prototype means "accept any parameter" and may invoke an abomination called "the default argument promotions". Also, programmers measuring good programming practice in number of keystrokes need to find another career. Programming involves a whole lot of typing, see.

Comment: I thought engineers apply thought and work without rotely following some rule. In this context, if you prefer `int main(void)` we'll end this here. I've no comments further :)

Comment: @legends2k: Have you actually looked at the standard in detail? The 2 valid definitions given are `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` and equivalent. The _"equivalent"_  is explained in a footnote, saing that `int main (int argc, char **argv);` is valid, because it's compatible with `char *argv[]`. `int main()` is **not** equivalent, because it's compatible with `int main(struct foo *bar, double zar, const char **something);`, which is not valid according to the standard

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem He is likely referring to the text "or otherwise in some implementation-defined manner" from the standard. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/31263079#31263079) where this part of the standard is discussed below "C99 hosted environment".

Comment: @legends2k Indeed. The good software engineer would in this context would know the standard and then use their brain and be concerned about reduced type safety and reduced portability that potentially comes with `int main()`, compared to `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Lundin Agree. Applying thought in a design approach is a good idea. Applying thought in re-defining standard in order to justify the wrong usage is most probably a wastage of time, IMHO. :-)

Comment: @Lundin FWIW: [the standard clearly states that in a function definition an empty set of parameters has a well-defined behaviour: that the function does not take any parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225214/183120). The keystrokes was just an additional argument, really, the key point was readability. If I came across as brash, I didn't mean to.

Comment: @legends2k That answer is bad an contains incorrect statements. It is true that (6.7.6.3) "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters.". However, this is bad style and flagged as obsolete, see C11 future language extensions 6.11.6 "The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.". So if you write code as `int main()` your code might not compile in the next version of the standard.

Comment: Hopefully cleared this up by adding [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31336367/584518) to that other thread linked.

Comment: @Lundin Nice one, sir, :-) This link is a very useful link that will be used frequently, I assume. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
int(*ptr)[5];//array of pointer.
ptr=&var;
```

wouldn't compile *error: assigning to 'int (*)[5]' from incompatible type 'int *'*. `ptr` is not an `int` pointer but a pointer to an array of 5 integers, hence they're incompatible for assignment.

Even if you coerce the compiler with an explicit cast, this

```
printf("Value inside ptr after ptr=&var : %u\n",ptr[1]);
```

is clearly undefined behaviour since you'd be accessing beyond what is allowed.

> why value and address of ptr[0] is same

Once you get undefined behaviour, all bets are off! Please read about [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/183120).

Answer (score 0):

The value of a pointer might be determined by printing.

```
*ptr[0]
```

Since this is the proper syntax. Also if you print the address of prt[0] using

```
&ptr[0]
```

it will give the same address as of the var variable because it will automatically assign the 0'th index in the array of integer with the var.
To check results, you might use the modified code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var=100;
    int(*ptr)[5]; 

    ptr=&var;
    printf("Value of var is  : %d\n",var); // it will print 100.
    printf("Address of var : %u\n",&var);  // it will print an address.
    printf("Value inside ptr after ptr=&var : %u\n",*ptr[0]); // it will print 100.
    printf("Value of ptr[0] is  : %d\n", *ptr[0]); // it will print 100.
    printf("Address of ptr[0] is  : %u\n",&ptr[0]); // it will print the address same as var.

    printf("Value of ptr[1] is  : %d\n",*ptr[1]); // it will print garbage value.
    printf("Address of ptr[1] is  : %u\n",&ptr[1]); // Address.

    printf("Value of ptr[2] is  : %d\n",*ptr[2]); // garbage value
    printf("Address of ptr[2] is  : %u\n",&ptr[2]); // Address.
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my output.

```
Value of var is  : 100
Address of var : 1386442756
Value inside ptr after ptr=&var : 100
Value of ptr[0] is  : 100
Address of ptr[0] is  : 1386442756
Value of ptr[1] is  : -87802171
Address of ptr[1] is  : 1386442776
Value of ptr[2] is  : 32767
Address of ptr[2] is  : 1386442796
```