# Whats wrong with this C code?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

My sourcecode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char myArray[150];
    int n = sizeof(myArray);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i + 1; 
        printf("%d\n", myArray[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14 and gcc to compile it, what it prints out is:

```
1
2
3
...
125
126
127
-128
-127
-126
-125
...
```

Why doesn't it just count up to 150?

Comment: Doesn't it seem suspicious to you that it stops at 127 (2^7-1) ?

Comment: Unpleasant is also, that you are using an `int` where a `size_t` should be used, as `sizeof` evaluates to such. Also it should at least be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @alk Why is `int main()` incorrect?

Comment: Never use the plain `char` type for anything but strings. Instead, use `uint8_t`.

Comment: @FUZxxl It may be correct on some freestanding systems but I doubt it. In most versions of C, it is incorrect. It is however perfectly fine in C++. [Complete reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @Lundin Beginning with C99, an empty parameter list in a function *definition* specifies a function taking zero arguments, therefore `int main()` is valid and equal to `int main(void)`. Furthermore, the standard only specifies that the type of `main` shall be compatible to one of the two types provided. Even in C89, `int main()` is compatible to `int main(int, char**)`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Beginning with C99, empty parameter list (in declaration or definition) is also an obsolete feature which may be removed in the next version of the language. Unfortunately they didn't remove it in C11, so lets hope such stupid nonsense gets removed in Cxx.

Comment: @FUZxxl [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid/31336367#31336367).

Comment: @Lundin What might be removed is an empty parameter list meaning “this function takes arbitrary arguments of arbitrary type.” The fact that the committee decided that an empty parameter list in a definition means “no argument” is a pretty good hint at what an empty parameter list is going to mean in a declaration once they remove this obsolete feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your compiler by default considers type `char` like type `signed char`. In this case `CHAR_MIN` is equal to `SCHAR_MIN` and in turn equal to `-128` while `CHAR_MAX` is equal to `SCHAR_MAX` and in turn equal to `127` (See header `<limits.h>`)

According to the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 15 The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are
>   collectively called the character types. The implementation shall
>   define char to have the same range, representation, and **behavior as
>   either signed char or unsigned char**

For signed types one bit is used as the sign bit. So for the type `signed char` the maximum value corresponds to the following representation in the hexadecimal notation

```
0x7F
```

and equal to 127. The most significant bit is the signed bit and is equal to 0.

For negative values the signed bit is set to 1 and for example `-128` is represented like

```
0x80
```

When in your program the value stored in char reaches its positive maximum `0x7F`and was increased it becomes equal to `0x80` that in the decimal notation is equal to `-128`.

You should explicitly use type `unsigned char` instead of the `char` if you want that the result of the program execution did not depend on the compiler settings.

Or in the printf statement you could explicitly cast type `char` to type `unsigned char`. For example

```
printf("%d\n", ( unsigned char )myArray[i]);
```

Or to compare results you could write in the loop

```
printf("%d %d\n", myArray[i], ( unsigned char )myArray[i]);
```

Comment: Sir, I don't think the reason is compiler dependent. It is the format specifier of printf, '%d' in this case that is causing this. This is in no way, related to 'char' as a data type.

Comment: @vish4071 You are wrong. When the argument is promoted from type char to type int its signedness is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

`int` value of a `char` can range from 0 to 255 or -127 to 127, depending on implementation.
Therefore once the value reaches 127 in your case, it overflows and you get negative value as output.

Comment: Far more commonly two's complement, from -128 to 127. Perhaps this is what you meant.

Comment: It should be noted that signed integer overflow is undefined in C.

Answer (score 2):

The signedness of a plain `char` is implementation defined.

In your case, a `char` is a `signed char`, which can hold the value of a range to -128 to +127.

As you're incrementing the value of `i` beyond the limit `signed char` can hold and trying to assign the same to `myArray[i]` you're facing an implementation-defined behaviour.

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.3.1.4,

> 3. Otherwise, the new type is `signed` and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `char` is a ***SIGNED BYTE***. That means it's value range is -128 -> 127.

> EDIT Due to all the below comment suggesting this is wrong / not the issue / signdness / what not...

Running this code:

```
char a, b;
unsigned char c, d;
int si, ui, t;
t = 200;

a = b = t;
c = d = t;
si = a + b;
ui = c + d;

printf("Signed:%d | Unsigned:%d", si, ui);
```

Prints: Signed:-112 | Unsigned:400
[Try yourself](https://repl.it/BBnB)

The reason is the same. `a` & `b` are signed chars (signed variables of size byte - 8bits). `c` & `d` are unsigned. Assigning 200 to the signed variables overflows and they get the value -56. In memory, `a`, `b,`c`&`d` all hold the same value, but when used their type "signdness" dictates how the value is used, and in this case it makes a big difference.

#### Note about standard

It has been noted (in the comments to this answer, as well as other answers) that the standard doesn't mandate that char is signed. That is true. However, in the case presented by OP, as well the code above, char IS signed.

Comment: *Because a char is a SIGNED BYTE*. Wrong, the standard doesn't say whether it's signed or unsigned. And you got 3 upvotes, shame on the upvoters.

Comment: `a char is a SIGNED BYTE`..can you quote something?

Comment: @cnicutar - You're right regarding standard, I'm right regarding what happened (`myArray` IS an array of signed bytes...)

Comment: @Amit Ummm.. I think no, as this is UB. So, nothing's guaranteed.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - are you referring to the use of the term byte vs. char? if so, what I meant is that it's a signed value in a byte sized variable

Comment: @cnicutar Just to make it clear, signedness of `char` is implementation defined, overflow of signed type is UB. Right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Right. I figured you were talking about overflow.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, cnicutar. Beyond the discussion of UB's overflows & standards.. In terms of answering the question (*Whats wrong with this C code*, *Why doesn't it just count up to 150?*), Isn't my answer correct in your opinion(s)? Is it not that the "8 bit" variable used (array of actually) has a range of -128 -> 127?

Comment: @Amit, your answer is conceptually wrong, whether you think it explains the scenario here or not, is totally different.

Comment: And char is actually `unsigned` according to standard. So, your answer is essentially wrong

Comment: @vish4071 so if it's unsigned according to standard, Is the compiler used not following the standard, or is there any other reason why the output was as it was?

Comment: The reason is not compiler here. It is the format specifier of printf, '%d' in this case that is causing this, as %d prints signed int values. This is in no way, related to 'char' as a data type.

Comment: @vish4071 you're wrong. bluntly wrong. change the array type to `int ..[]` and everything will work just fine.in this case `char` IS signed, and overflows on assignment. After that manipulating with format specifiers doesn't change the value, just the representation

Comment: @Amit, that is because int is 4 bytes and 8th bit is not the sign-bit then.

Comment: @vish4071 see edited answer, I hope you understand now.

Comment: hmm, ok @Amit, I get it now.