# Inorder , Preorder and Postorder traversals

Tags: c, inorder, preorder, postorder

I wrote a C program to input elements of a binary search tree and display its InOrder, PostOrder and PreOrder traversals.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct tnode
{
    int data;
    struct tnode *leftc;
    struct tnode *rightc;
};
int main()
{
    char ans='N';
    struct tnode *new_node,*root;
    //  struct tnode *get_node();
    root=NULL;
    do{
        // new_node=get_node();
        printf("\nEnter the Element");
        scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
        if(root==NULL)
            root=new_node;
        else
            insert(root,new_node);
        printf("\nDo you want to enter a new element?(y/n)");
        scanf("%c",&ans);
    }while(ans == 'y');
    printf("Inorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    inorder(root);
    printf("\nPreorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    preorder(root);
    printf("Postorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    postorder(root);
    return 0;
}
void insert(struct tnode ** tree,int num)
{
    struct tnode *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp=(struct tnode *)malloc(sizeof (struct tnode));
        temp->leftc=temp->rightc=NULL;
        temp->data=num;
        *tree=temp;
        return;
    }
    if(num < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->leftc,num);
    }
    else if(num > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->rightc,num);
    }
}
void preorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
        preorder(s->leftc);
        preorder(s->rightc);
    }
}
void inorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        inorder(s->leftc);
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
        inorder(s->rightc);
    }
}
void postorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        postorder(s->leftc);
        postorder(s->rightc);
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
    }
}
```

I am getting these warning messages:

```
warning: implicit declaration of functionS,
conflicting types OF FUNCTIONS,
new_node’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

I can't understand the errors.Can you please help me fix these?

Comment: Please indent the code, otherwise I'm not looking at it.

Comment: Didn't look at the code, but regarding the first warning: In C you must declare functions before you use therm. In fact you must declare *everything* before you use it. As for the other, do you initialize the `new_node` variable before you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C in order to use function you need to declare em before main function like in your case you should write :

```
void insert(struct tnode ** tree,int num);
//all declarations of other functions here .
```

//btw you can declare em without the names of variables like this :

```
void insert(struct tnode ** , int );
```

also just try to google Binary Search Tree in C .
There are many websites that shows exactly the answer you are looking for and plenty of websites that got tutorials that explain everything around it.

*P.S 
if you don't want to declare the functions before the main function , you can just put the ready functions that you have upper of a main and main function should be at bottom at end.*

Answer (score 2):

- You have to declare or define functions to use *before* you use them.
- Your usage of `insert()` is wrong.
- Using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*. In this case, you don't have to use the struct to read the data for new node.
- What you don't expect may be read into `ans`. Add a space before format specifier`%c` to have `scanf()` skip whitespace chracter before reading a character.
- You should use one of standard signatures of `main()`. In C, `int main()` and `int main(void)` [have different meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid).
- You should format your code properly.
- They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct tnode
{
    int data;
    struct tnode *leftc;
    struct tnode *rightc;
};
/* declare functions */
void insert(struct tnode ** tree,int num);
void preorder(struct tnode * s);
void inorder(struct tnode * s);
void postorder(struct tnode * s);
/* use one of the standard forms of main() */
int main(void)
{
    char ans='N';
    struct tnode *root;
    int new_node_data;
    //  struct tnode *get_node();
    root=NULL;
    do{
        // new_node=get_node();
        printf("\nEnter the Element");
        scanf("%d",&new_node_data); /* do not dereference indeterminate pointer */
        insert(&root,new_node_data); /* pass correct data */
        printf("\nDo you want to enter a new element?(y/n)");
        scanf(" %c",&ans); /* add a space before %c to have scanf() skip whitespace characters */
    }while(ans == 'y');
    printf("Inorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    inorder(root);
    printf("\nPreorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    preorder(root);
    printf("Postorder traversal:the elements in the tree are");
    postorder(root);
    return 0;
}
void insert(struct tnode ** tree,int num)
{
    struct tnode *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp=malloc(sizeof (struct tnode));
        temp->leftc=temp->rightc=NULL;
        temp->data=num;
        *tree=temp;
        return;
    }
    if(num < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->leftc,num);
    }
    else if(num > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->rightc,num);
    }
}
void preorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
        preorder(s->leftc);
        preorder(s->rightc);
    }
}
void inorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        inorder(s->leftc);
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
        inorder(s->rightc);
    }
}
void postorder(struct tnode * s)
{
    if(s)
    {
        postorder(s->leftc);
        postorder(s->rightc);
        printf("%d\n",s->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. but in the output only the first element is getting printed for all 3 traversals

Comment: @joejoe [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DeQ813IWJy5Y6Bib).