# Function of main() in C programming

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am working in the C programming language. What is the function of `main()`? What is `void main()` and `int main()`?

Comment: `main`is the start of the user code. It is where your program starts. Lookup `main` in the cmpiler manual or on-line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int main() and int main(void)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid)

Comment: `main()` is the defined start point for all C programs - the first user-defined function called when a program starts.   `int main()` is specified in the standard.  `void main()` is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

It is the entry point of a C program.  See here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++

Answer (score 1):

> What is the function of `main()`?

It is the [**entry point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) of your program. That's the first function which is executed when you run your program.

---

> What is the difference between `void main()` and `int main()`?

- The ***valid*** syntax for the `main()` function is:

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```

  It can also take arguments. [**See more here.**](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html)
- The second syntax is ***not valid***:

  ```
  void main(void)
  ```

That's because your `main()` should return the [**exit status**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) of your program.

Comment: what is  the role of main() function  in programming?

Comment: Since it's the entry point, you will use it to write the base of your program. Call your other functions, etc.

Comment: thanks.Why  int main is valid syntax and void main is invalid syntax ?

Comment: @NirmalDC Because `void main()` means that `main()` won't return anything. So you can't do `return 0` (or any other exit status). Your `main()` needs to be defined with `int main()` so that you can return an exit status.

Answer (score 1):

[Best answer of Brian-Bi](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-int-main-void-main-and-main-function-in-the-C-programing-language/answer/Brian-Bi):

> - `void main() { ... }` is **wrong**. If you're declaring main this way, stop. (Unless your code is running in a freestanding environment, in
>     which case it could theoretically be correct.)
> - `main() { ... }` is acceptable in `C89`; the return type, which is not specified, defaults to `int`. However, this is no longer allowed in
>     **C99**. Therefore...
> - `int main() { ... }` is the best way to write main if you don't care about the program arguments. If you care about program arguments,
>     you need to declare the **argc** and **argv** parameters too. You should
>     always define main in this way. Omitting the return type offers no
>     advantage in `C89` and will break your code in `C99`.