# What's wrong with this function that reverses arrays using recursivity? ( code and outcome included )

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, reverse, function-definition

So this is the code I wrote, trying to reverse that array t using recursivity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rev(int n, float *t)
{
    float x;
    if(n==0)
  {
     return 0 ;
  }
  else
  {
       x=*t;
       *t=*(t+(n-1));
       *(t+(n-1))=x;
       return rev(n-1, t+1);
  }
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    float t[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int n=sizeof t /sizeof *t;
    rev (n,t);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%f",t[i]);
}
```

I'd like to understand why this solution does not work, I'm not that interested in the solution overall but I want to understand what mistakes I made in this one for it not to work.
[image: Outcome after execution]

Comment: `main()` must return `int`. Variables can/should be declared in narrower scopes. Add some spaces between your `printf()` outputs to make them understandable.

Comment: Read  [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)..). See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). With GCC, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info) then use `gdb`. Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source programs, e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or others on [github](https://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters a function that has the return type `void` shall return nothing value. So this statement

```
return 0 ;
```

is invalid.

The function swaps two elements so the size of the array must be decremented by 2.

The function can look like

```
void rev( float a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        float tmp = *a;
        *a = *( a + n - 1 );
        *( a + n - 1 ) = tmp;
        rev( a + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}
```

and be called like

```
size_t n = sizeof t /sizeof *t;
rev( t, n);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rev( float a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        float tmp = *a;
        *a = *( a + n - 1 );
        *( a + n - 1 ) = tmp;
        rev( a + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    float a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    size_t n = sizeof a /sizeof *a;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.0f ", a[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    rev( a, n );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.0f ", a[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

instead of

```
void main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are small easy to fix problems like `return 0;` and `return rev(n-1, t+1);`. The first one should be just

```
return;
```

because you can't return anything from a function returning `void`.

The other should be a call to `rev()` itself

```
rev(n-1, t+1);
```

because that's what recursive functions do (and also because you can't return anything)

Then you should use `int main( void )` or at least `int main()` [Difference between int main() and int main(void)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225171/difference-between-int-main-and-int-mainvoid)

Finally, you have a logic error here

```
x=*t;
*t=*(t+(n-1));
*(t+(n-1))=x;

rev(n-1, t+1);
```

`*(t+(n-1))` will always be the value of the last element of the array: yes you pass `n-1` so you expect that if `*(t+(n-1))` was 8th element, in the next call it will be 7th, however you are also passing `t+1` so `*(t+(n-1))` will always be the 8th element of the array.

And even this one is an easy-to-fix problem. You just pass `n-2`.

Here's your recursive function

```
void rev(int n, float *t)
{
    float x;
    
    if(n > 0) { 
    
        x=*t;
        *t=*(t+(n-1));
        *(t+(n-1))=x;
        
        rev(n-2, t+1);
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Doing

```
if(n != 0) {
    .... something....
}

return;
```

Is the same of doing

```
if(n == 0) {
    return;
}
else {
    ... something...
}
```

I put `n > 0` instead of `n != 0` because since n is always initially positive the two conditions are equivalent, however since you pass `n-2` if `n` is an odd number you are going to have negative values of `n` without passing for 0.