# c++ visual studio error, im confused

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I keep getting an error: unexpected end-of-file found and i am completely lost. I have checked the curry braces and the parentheses I have put a semicolon at the end of the class I cant figure out whats wrong with it. thanks alot.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



class operations{
    void checkout(){
        cout << "Check out here!!";
    }
}
void main(){
    string item;
    int choice;

    cout << "What do you want to do? " << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 for checking out " << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 for stocking " << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 looking at recipts " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << choice;

    if(choice == 1){
        void checkout();
    }
    /*ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("inventory.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()){
        cout << "Enter a grocery item" << endl;
        getline(cin,item);
        myfile << item;
    }
    cout << "Your grocery item is " << item;
    myfile.close();
    system("pause");*/
};
```

Comment: You put a semicolon at the end of the `main()` function, not at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: Also, the call to `void checkout();` within `main()` is not syntactically valid.  First, because you don't write the return type (`void` in this case) when you call a function, and second, because `checkout()` is a member function, not a standalone function, so you have to call it on an object that's an instance of the `operations` class.

Comment: i'm still getting the error.it says its at line 39, but my program only has 38 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code, corrected as I interpreted what you wanted to perform.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class operations
{
    public:void checkout()
    {
        cout << "Check out here!!";
    }
};

int main()
{
    string item;
    int choice;
    operations op;

    cout << "What do you want to do? " << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 for checking out " << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 for stocking " << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 looking at recipts " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << choice;

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        op.checkout();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

First, note that semicolons are needed after class declarations, and not needed after method declarations

Second, note that `void checkout()` in your code would not call the method that you defined in your class, but will instead declare a new method that will simply perform nothing. To call the right `void checkout()` you have to instatiate an object of type `operations` and then call its method with `op.checkout()`

Last, always declare `int main()` and place `return 0` if the executions flow arrives to the end of your program correctly.

As a side note, I would probably not use a class in your program, but simply implement the methods correspondent to the user's choice before the `main()` implementation

```
void checkout()
{
    cout << "Check out here!!";
}
```

so that you can call them simply with

```
checkout()
```

Comment: There was no need to add `return 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your class definition needs a trailing semi-colon, not your main function.

   ```
   class operations{
       void checkout(){
           cout << "Check out here!!";
       }
   };
   ```
2. "void main" is wrong.  `main` always returns `int`.

Comment: while you are right and `main` should return `int', VC++ accept `void main`

Comment: @BigBoss, But it's technically undefined behaviour to have it in a hosted environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main

Answer (score -2):

I think you should add this in the top of your file(make this the first line):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: There's no indication at all that precompiled headers have anything at all to do with this.