# Returning zero from main breaks my program

Tags: c++

I just begin to learn C++, for the main method i do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int d;
   int n;
   cout <<"Enter the denominator: " << endl;
   cin >> d;
   cout <<"Enter the numerator: " << endl;
   cin >> n;
   cout <<"The result of operation is: " << endl;
   cout << (double)n/d << endl;
   cout <<"Done";
   return 0;
}
```

It doesn't produce output, but if I delete return 0. I will generate correct output. Shouldn't the main method in C++ always return an integer eventually?

Comment: The function `main` is a special case, as there (and only there) doesn't have to be a `return` statement even though the function returns an `int`. If there's no explicit `return` statement, `0` is returned. [basic.start.main]/5

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/636829/335858) for a discussion of what `main()` is supposed to return.

Comment: -1 for the meaningless title.

Comment: Perhaps the window closes right away after printing out the result?

Comment: Your code [works perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/lLnsbs) with `return 0` present.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't produce output"?  You don't even see the first two prompts?  You don't see the "Done."? Or what exactly?  A `main()` that "executes" to the closing `}` will implicitly perform a `return 0;`. So there should be exactly no difference whether or not you have the `return 0;` as posted in the question.

Comment: No doubt running a console program and it closes right away. Try asking for a keypress using something like cin.get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your code and everything seems to be right. When I run it, it works fine. If you haven't solved it yet try to cut and past your code into a new project. I know that it sounds stupid but it should work.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I have no ideas what exactly the problem it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cout.flush();` before return.
It forces the buffered data to be send to the output.

Comment: As does program exit, so I'm not sure that will help.

Comment: `endl` and the `cin` operations also force the output buffer to be flushed.