# Recursive function with function template

Tags: c++, function, templates, recursion

I am fairly new to programming. When I build this program I do not get any errors using visual express. But when I run it without debugging it displays the first `cout` statement and the answer to the function call `number` and then crashes. Can anyone tell me what may be wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// This program demonstrates a recursive function.
// The function should accept two arguments, the 
// number to be raised and the exponent. A function 
// template is used to test different data types.
// Assume that the exponent is a nonnegative integer.


template <class T, class TT>
T number(T raised, TT exponent)
{
 if (exponent == 0)
  return 1;
 else 
  return raised * number(raised, exponent -1);
}

void main()
{
// Testing integers
cout << "Testing integers: 5 raised to 2 is "
     << number(5, 2) << endl;

// Testing doubles
cout << "Testing doubles: 5.5 raised to 2.2 is "
     << setprecision(1) << number(5.5, 2.2) << endl;

// Testing floats
cout << "Testing doubles: 5.55 raised to 2.22 is "
     << setprecision(4) << number(5.55f, 2.22f) << endl;

// Testing a double and a integer
cout << "Testing integers: 5.5 raised to 2 is "
     << number(5.5, 2) << endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**  Thank you for the responses. I understand now. I will adjust `if(exponent == 0)`

Comment: The algorithm you're using only works for integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the recursion:

```
if(exponent == 0) return 1;
```

What you don't account for is if the number is a `double`, such as `2.2`. After decreasing it by 1 twice it will reach `.2` and then `-0.8`. Never once will it reach `0`. This causes a stack overflow as the recursion depth exceeds the stack.

Also `void main()` is [not the right way to define main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main).

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response. I will change it to `if(exponent < 1) return 1;` I won't get the exact answer but I'll be in range unless there is something I can do to make it work better.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, you could help by accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

You broke this assumption:

```
// Assume that the exponent is a nonnegative integer.
```

The recursive function works for integer exponents because, eventually, subtracting one from the exponent will give zero, and the function will return.

Passing a non-integer value, such as `2.2`, will cause it to recursively call the function with `1.2`, `0.2`, `-0.8`, `-1.8`, and so on until the stack explodes.

In C++11, you could enforce the assumption with, for example,

```
static_assert(std::is_integral<TT>::value, "Exponent must be an integer");
```

although you could still have problems if the integer value is too large.