# inheritance derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I got an error (It says the Euro_call is inaccessible) when I try to initialize the derived class.  Is there any way to fix the error without significant change of the code? I welcome any advice.

```
class Euro{
protected:
double S;     // spot price

public:
Euro(const double&);
~Euro(){};
};

Euro::Euro(const double& _s):S(_s){}


class Euro_call:public Euro{    
public:
Euro_call(const double&);
~Euro_call(){};
};

Euro_call::Euro_call(const double& _s):Euro(_s){};

class main{
Euro_call a(2.0);   
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to define `main` as a class?

Comment: If you replace `class main{` with `void main(){ Euro_call a(2.0); }` then it should compile.

Comment: Thank you^^. I am just a beginner of learning c++ and didn't realize the small mistake.

Comment: @flatmouse `void main()` is undefined behavior or a compilerextension. Please use one of the valid entry points, like `int main()`

Comment: @nvoigt Good point, I've tried to clarify in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is missing an [entry point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

The `class main{` [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636834/1460794) `int main() {`, and the program may return 0 to indicate successful completion to the operating system.

---

There is also a redundant `;` at the end of:

> ```
> Euro_call::Euro_call(const double& _s) :Euro(_s) {};
> ```

---

So [the full program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6de90efbf4cf23f), with changes to the last 4 lines:

```
class Euro {
protected:
    double S;     // spot price

public:
    Euro(const double&);
    ~Euro() {};
};

Euro::Euro(const double& _s) :S(_s) {}


class Euro_call :public Euro {
public:
    Euro_call(const double&);
    ~Euro_call() {};
};

Euro_call::Euro_call(const double& _s) :Euro(_s) {}

int main() {
    Euro_call a(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```