# "expected'; ',' or 'or') 'before' * 'token" error when using structure

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

all

I have a few problems with using structures.
The source is shown below.

### main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "info.h"

_Rbuffer Rb;

void write(_Rbuffer Rb *rb)
{
    printf("write function\n");
}


void main(void)
{

    printf("Hello World\n");

}
```

### info.h

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Button1;
} _Rbuffer;

extern _Rbuffer Rb;
```

When compiling, the following error occurs.

```
root@test-VirtualBox:~/sample# gcc main.c
main.c:6:24: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void write(_Rbuffer Rb *rb)
                        ^  
root@test-VirtualBox:~/sample#
```

I am currently unable to change info.h.

I declare a structure and I do not know why an error occurs.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `_Rbuffer Rb *rb` makes no sense. What are you trying to declare? (Note also that the name `_Rbuffer` is reserved for the implementation. Programs are not allowed to use names that begin with an underscore and capital letter.)

Comment: What you have is basically `int a * b`, which is a syntax error, as you see. Either `write(_Rbuffer Rb)` or  `write(_Rbuffer *rb)` would compile. Whether this is what you want, though, I haven't a clue.

Comment: Names starting underscore followed by capital letter are reserved for implementation use.  Also, if you intend to use posix code, you shouldn't call your function `write`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You should use `int main` instead of `void main` .

2 You should use `void write(_Rbuffer *rb)` instead of `void write(_Rbuffer Rb *rb)` .

Comment: It is not obvious what kind of system this is for, so 1) is a pointless comment. `void main (void)` is fine and standard-compliant on freestanding systems.

Comment: @Lundin "The definition void main() is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C."  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080996/7671328

Comment: That particular quote is actually infamous for being very much incorrect. Stroustrup is confused over many language details... The truth is found in the standard, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for you advice. But I am confused. And I will use `int main` instead of `void main` in the future.

Comment: Roughly, it can be summarized as `int main (...)` is the correct form to use on hosted systems (running on OS) and versions like `void main (void)` is the correct form to use on freestanding systems (embedded systems/microcontrollers). C and C++ are quite similar here. Stroustrup was ignorant of the existence of embedded systems when he made that failed comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
void write(_Rbuffer Rb *rb)
{
printf("write function\n");
}
```

you passed in Rb, but you also pointed at *rb

if you want to modify Rb, then

```
void write(_Rbuffer* Rb)
```

if you just want to a copy of your Rb, then

```
void write (_Rbuffer Rb)
```