# MPICH: After MPI_COMM_SPAWN spawned child can't reach parent node

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I'm trying to create a master slave configuration of processes between two 2 nodes.

Node1 spawns N processes at Node2. My problem is that when the spawned processes try to communicate with their parent node. They try to connect to 127.0.1.1 IP which is the IP assigned to Node1 on /etc/hosts file of Node1.

My /etc/hosts files are like this

Node1 /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  node1
ip.node.2  node2
...
```

Node2 /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  node2
ip.node.1  node1
...
```

This is my error

```
MPIR_Init_thread(506)............................: 
MPID_Init(325)...................................: spawned process group was unable to connect back to the parent on port <tag#0$description#madx$port#60313$ifname#127.0.1.1$>
MPID_Comm_connect(191)...........................: 
MPIDI_Comm_connect(834)..........................: Named port tag#0$description#madx$port#60313$ifname#127.0.1.1$ does not exist
MPIDI_Comm_connect(651)..........................: 
MPIDI_Create_inter_root_communicator_connect(324): Connection timed out in 180 seconds
```

And my master.c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int kernels, servers;
    char hostname[256];
    gethostname(hostname, 255);
    //char nombre[10]; int longitud;
    kernels = atoi(argv[1]);
    servers = atoi(argv[2]);

    MPI_Comm intercomm;
    MPI_Info info[2];

    MPI_Info_create(&info[0]);
    MPI_Info_set(info[0], "hostfile", "host2.txt");
    MPI_Info_create(&info[1]);
    MPI_Info_set(info[1], "hostfile", "host2.txt");

    char *cmds[2] = {"./kernel", "./server"};
    int np[2] = {kernels, servers};
    int errcodes[2];
    MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple(2, cmds, MPI_ARGVS_NULL, np, info, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, errcodes);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

host2.txt

```
host2:4
```

Comment: Why don’t you fix your `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: I just added how my /etc/hosts are right now. I think they are properly written.

Comment: Please don't use [`void main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main)!

Comment: @andreee Thanks, I thought it was the same.

Comment: Your `/etc/hosts` should be identical on both nodes with `ip.node.1 node1` and `ip.node.2 node2`